# Microcontrollers and Python

Tags: microcontroller, python

So I am fairly new to robotics however I do have some background with the python coding language. Recently I set myself the task of learning some basics for robotics just to increase my knowledge base.

My question is about micro-controllers and specifically if I need to buy a certain type of microcontroller to be able to program with the python language. Also are there any recommended python libraries or starting points for robotics with python? I apologize if this question is a bit broad or not well formed as I am very new to understanding microcontrollers.

Thank you

Comment: this may help .... https://github.com/micropython/micropython/wiki/Boards-Summary

Answer (score 2):

You may also consider the 
[PyBoard](https://store.micropython.org/)  which has a microcontroller specifically configured to run Python ([Micropython](http://micropython.org/)).  There are many addon 'shield' board for robotics-related components and a book that will help to get started.

[image: PyBoard 1.1 from their website (Mar 2019)]

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest ways to get started with python and robots has to be the microbit: https://microbit.org/

[image: Microbit]

There are many different robot platform which you can buy:
[image: Legged Robot]

Or with wheels:
[image: Wheeled Robot]